# How to capture the refresh inside of an iframe from parent document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

Here's the case:
We have a file upload page. We didn't want to reload the page once the upload is done, so we put the form inside of an iframe. The form inside of an iframe posts to itself and returns json when it's done. How can we capture that response? When upload is done, the iframe reloads, so in other words, how do we capture when the iframe is reloaded?

Assume these:

- we cannot print/return anything except the json object (so no js code to call the function in a parent document.)
- we cannot use ajax since you cannot post files using ajax
- we cannot append javascript code inside of iframe, because once the form inside of iframe is submitted, the page gets reloaded and we lose the appended js code.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** - Seems like the solution is super simple (found it somewhere online):

```
<iframe onload="alert(window['upload_iframe'].document.body.innerHTML);"  ...></iframe>
```

This way, it will fire the alert whenever page inside of an iframe is reloaded. Now it's just matter of differentiating JSON object from HTML code, which is pretty simple. Thanks for everyone for a great advises!

Comment: Why can you not return anything except a JSON object? That seems like a really awkward constraint you are setting on yourselves there.

Comment: @glenatron json is returned from the java servlet. as I understand (i'm not back-end guy), there's one general class which is used throughout other servlets, and it "builds" and returns the json... we usually use these servlets via ajax, but not in this case.. so since when the page is loaded, there's nowhere to send json, so it prints that json... I just need a way to capture that json without changing the general java class.. I hope I didn't confuse you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried appending an "onload" listener to the iframe element to see if when the iframe source is changed it's triggered?  That might be a solution.  If it doesn't work, then I don't think you have a choice but to execute a top level function from the iframe result.

**update**

Since you don't have control over the response from the servlet, perhaps you could build a PHP median that communicates with the servlet and takes the raw json it gets and then returns what it needs to execute a parent window javscript function and passing the json to that function.

This way you control the output.

Comment: I can append the onload listener inside the iframe, but once the form is submitted, iframe reloads and I'll lose that listener... if there was a way to capture the completed form submission (and it may take x amount of time since it's uploading a file), I could get the json straight from inside of the iframe..

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the content of the iFrame has changed by performing a timed check of the inner text of the iFrame document against whatever it was last time you checked ( or a hash of it if the document is large ) and then once it has changed you could try parsing the content as JSON to check it is the expected response.

Alternately you could use AJAX to check whether the upload has completed on the server side and once the server confirms that it has finished uploading you can then check the iFrame content.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing the first option, but I'm looking for a better solutions, because it's not the best way to go I guess... The second concept sounds good, but it will make things a lot complicated on the server side, and if you consider that there are hundreds of users who may be uploading files at the same time, that sounds a bit complicated... but I'll check with back-end guys. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't an ideal solution, but you are not in an ideal situation- if you were designing from the bottom up you would have more control over the output of the upload script, but from where you are this should offer something that works. Whatever you do here is likely to be something of a hack.